# Ruby Programmer collaboration with Graphics Designer: Best practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphics

I've been programming for many years and have just recently got the RoR "itch". I'm thinking about how I could utilize a graphic designer and wondered how best to collaborate with them:

1) Do scaffolding and then show them where to place the graphics in the views (seems ugly)

2) Have them do screens and make them keep a certain dir structure for all media links i.e. /public/images public/stylesheets, etc. Will this confuse the graphics designer LOL?

3) Better to just have them build the images (like a header or footer image, etc.) and place them in yourself. But this approach means you have to start thinking about design and layout which seems better left to the graphics specialist.

All of the above seem flawed to me and I was wondering if there are any "best practices" for this problem? Searched for articles, etc., but didn't find much. Suggestions? Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i work in a company that works 100% with ruby on rails development. which approach we take to integrate views.

First thing that we develop are views. The design team develop a view, tell us which data will be filled in this view and our development team develop the necessary ERB code. So normally a development process are like:

- We develop some views with the client
- Our dev team do the spec for functions
- The design give to us the application layout
- We implement it and start to work in the first models and controllers spec'ed
- New whishes and views will be asked by the client, that will be sent by our design team and  it will be spec'ed by our dev team.

Answer (score 1):

Normally give them their own rails server, teach them the basics of where they need to add controllers and views (no need for any model stuff) to work with the default route.

I integrate the HTML, they stick in the CSS.

Teaching them how to render partials helps them with consistency. Think that's about it.

Comment: Sounds like you have a pretty technical set of designers! I can't imagine having them even touching the controllers!

Comment: Our designers can understand Ruby, albeit they don't like HAML and SASS, but I don't blame them for that. 

The key to understand here is that developers shouldn't lead the direction for the website, they tend to have an overall better grip over web standards, more so than developers, as well as having the creative/artistic flair which a lot of developers lack.

Sure, it's good to help designers sometimes with some technical decisions but you kinda want the UX/UI people doing the work with regards to assisting the client during paper prototyping and site story collection.